# Associating a User to model via id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, polymorphic-associations

I'm having some difficulty expressing a linkage of a User to my Listing model.

I set up a Rails form when I associated a `designer_id` (added to listing_params as a private controller method) that would link a selected user to a Listing model when created:

```
#migration
add_column :listings, :designer_id, :integer

_form.html.erb
<%= collection_select :listing, :designer_id, @account.users, :id, :name, prompt: "Choose..." %>
```

Checking in the console, the form returned the correct user id as `designer_id`. Success!

What I need to do now is access the User name using a Listing method, but I'm getting stuck- the issue is primarily making the translation from the id procured to the User referenced:

```
 #listing.rb

  def designer
    self.designer_id == User.find_by_id(params[:name])
    if self.designer_id = nil
      return "N/A"
    else   
      return "#{User.name}"
  end
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the migration if you are on at least rails 4 you can do

`add_reference(:listings, :designer)`
you may need to do 
`add_reference(:listings, :designer, :foreign_key => { to_table: 'users'}`

other options I often use
`add_reference(:listings, :designer, :foreign_key => { to_table: 'users'} index: true, limit: 8)`

Migration aside you can do this in the models.

```
class Listing
  belongs_to :designer, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :listings


end
```

and in users

```
class User
  has_many :listings, inverse_of: :designer, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Getting the users name would then be,

`listing.designer.name`

if you are doing this in a controller you will want to pre-load the association so you are not introducing an n+1 query to a list of listings.

Comment: Aha! That did it. Can I load multiple classes (i.e. :designer, crew) onto `inverse_of`? Previously this just had a direct user <-> listing relationship, and that would automatically associated the current logged in user to the listing...

Comment: yes, sometimes, especially with user, you may need multiple associated to the item. The `inverse_of` is not actually needed to make it work, but helps when loading objects and seeing that the other is loaded too. Having them can avoid some unneeded queries. It's good idea to add them to all relations in rails. What is making `:designer` work is the `class_name: 'User`